# is there a way to train the models in batches? i m not talking about deep learning

Tags: machine-learning, python, predictive-models, dataset, large-data

I have 800,000 records. The training with all the records at once is not possible.
Is there a way i can train a model on 50k records then continue training on next 50k records and so on...

basically i dont want to start training all over again for the next batch, i want to continue training where i left off in the previous 50k batch

I am not using deep learning. I just want to train a simple linear regression model or may be a tree based model on a large dataset

Comment: Mini-batch training for a regression and a neural network proceed in exactly the same way. Trees would require something more complex, depending on what you goal is for the tree-based model. The simplest would probably be to fit several models on disjoint subsets and average predictions, but that might not meet your needs.

Comment: You can use partial_fit function (some machine learning models support this function [doc_sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/computing/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning)) and split your dataset into small batches

Answer (score 1):

There are several algorithms that are incremental like what you ask for, most of them are more or less based on [stochastic gradient descent (SGD)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) (this is also the principle behind the use of batches in neural networks). Primarily SGD works on one example at a time but you can also use it for one batch at a time.

SGD is an optimization algorithm that minimizes some loss that takes the form of an expectation (or a probability to be wrong), for example for linear models $E[(Y-\beta^T X)^2]$ in regression or $\log(1+\exp(-Y\beta^T X))$ in classification...

For tree based models, you can use [Boosting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting) that can also be used in batches.

The advantage is that you can train in batches as for neural networks but the disadvantage is that you must have a big database (this seems to be the case for you).

If you try to use SGD, as in the case of neural network be careful of the hyperparameters you choose. If you want a peek at an algorithm that works well for what you want to do with linear models see [scikit-learn SGDClassifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) or SGDRegressor and particularly partial_fit if you choose to use mini-batches. For trees, you can also look at scikit-learn or at xgboost library.